# Ajax call doesn't work when the ajax link is in the container to change

Tags: ajax, navigation

I found a topic on my problem but there was no answer..

I have a site with an ajax nav and it works perfectly with the principal nav but not with intern link. In fact, when the link which makes the Ajax call is in the content to be changed, it bugs (it works for the first click but not if you click on another intern link when the content is loaded). In this case, the page is reloaded...

http://miller-badger-76351.netlify.com/

You can test it on the link, intern link is "Découvre notre agence" on the main page and "Découvrez notre offre" on the Agence page (this is a french website).

```
$('a[class^="link"]').on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
_href = $(this).attr("href");
history.pushState(null, null, _href);


$('.content-yield').load('..' + _href + ' .contain', function(){
  window.scrollTo(0,0)   
});   // _href is the name of the html doc, for example, for the Agence page, the load string will be     '../l'agence/ .contain'
```

I hope that my problem is clear, I thank all of you in advance for your help =)

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution to this problem :

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[class^="link"]', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
_href = $(this).attr("href");
history.pushState(null, null, _href);


$('.content-yield').load('..' + _href + ' .contain', function(){
  window.scrollTo(0,0)   
});
```

You just have to select all your body and add the selector as a parameter !